# How can I learn to CREATE a data visualization tool in Python or in any other Language?

Tags: python, c++, visualization

I want to understand and learn how a data visualization tool works and is made.
Tried searching it on google but didn't found anything.
Only matplotlib tutorials.
I dont want to to learn to use a tool. I want to learn to create one.

Tried searching it on google but didn't found anything.
Expecting to get an online documentation/tutorial/course/YT playlist to learn it.
A long answer will work too. I will read it.

Comment: If you're hardcore, then check out Direct3D or OpenGL or Vulkan. For instance, OpenGL lets you draw triangles, lines, and points. Some day you will have graphics on par with things like POVRay. It's not easy though.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with learning to create plots from scratch. Since you tagged python, look up python visual libraries like [tk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) or [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to get started. Once you make some basic visuals of dots, try to make a graph template, then add some dummy data on top of it.